# SSH Connection Lost

Tags: ssh, iptables, connection

I have recently started using iptables, and I executed iptables -F without knowledge of what it might do. And suddenly I have lost connection to the node. I can't even ping the node. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

The `iptables -F` will have flushed (deleted) all of your rules, I guess your input policy is DROP so without any explicit ACCEPT rules you're locked out. Your best bet is to reboot the node and cross your fingers.

Answer (score 4):

You flushed all your iptables rules, including the default ACCEPT. You'll need to either reboot the server (and hope that it loads up a proper set of rules) or get on the console and fix it from there.

Comment: I forgot to mention. It's a virtual node! No physical access to get the console :-(

Comment: A proper VPS vendor will give you console access as well. I guess you'll need to reboot and hope for the best.

Comment: If you have a policy of accept then iptables -F doesn't lock you out - suck it and see.